# jquery selector returns sometimes empty object

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following piece of code that puts focus on textarea $newCommentBody field if the value of clicked radiobutton is 'not_important' or 'for_the_future'.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#inhabitant_request_realization').on('click', 'input[type=radio]', function () {
        var $newCommentBody = $('.fos_comment_comment_form_holder textarea'),
            $tooltiptext = $('.tooltiptext'),
            $this = $(this);

        if ($this.val() == 'not_important' || $this.val() == 'for_the_future') {
                $newCommentBody.focus();
                $tooltiptext.show();
        } else {
                $tooltiptext.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

The problem, actually is that $newCommentBody is loaded asynchronously and after i click the radio button the focus is sometimes put on textarea sometimes not because $newCommentBody is empty in that case.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: If you are loading your $newCommentBody by ajax add the click event listener on the success object. So it's not listening until the item loads.

Comment: thanks redconservatory! i've used ajaxStop event from http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/ and it solved my problem!